# How to compare a value that I read from a file and compare it to all the values in a queue?

Tags: c, queue

I am basically reading lines from a text file and saving it into a queue. However, a part of the line I need to make sure isn't duplicated so I need to have a function that would check if that string is already in the queue.

Here's my structure and part of the main function:

```
struct Runway0TakeOff{      
    char fdetails[10];
    int TakeOffHours;
    int TakeOffMins;
    int passengers;
    int WaitingTime;
    struct Runway0TakeOff *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct Runway0TakeOff RunZeroTakeOff;
typedef RunZeroTakeOff *RunZeroTakeOffPtr;

void AddToRunway0T(RunZeroTakeOffPtr *r0ThPtr, RunZeroTakeOffPtr *r0TtPtr, char fdetails[], int TakeOffHours, int TakeOffMins, int passengers);
int inTheSystem(RunZeroTakeOffPtr currentPtr, char fdetails[]);
int isEmpty(RunZeroTakeOffPtr r0ThPtr);

int main()
{
    int c, numberoflines, s, k, n, f, t;
    char  OptionCode[ROW][COLUMN], details[10], fdetails[10];

    int TakeOffHours, TakeOffMins, passengers, ArrivalTimeMins, ArrivalTimeHours;

    RunZeroTakeOffPtr r0ThPtr=NULL;
    RunZeroTakeOffPtr r0TtPtr=NULL;

    FILE * fPointer;
    fPointer = fopen("planes.txt","r");

    c=0;

    while ((c < ROW) && fgets(OptionCode[c], COLUMN, fPointer))
    { 
        ++c;
    }

    for(k=0;k<8;k++)
    {
        n=0;
        for (s = 2; s < 9; s++)
        {
            details[n] = OptionCode[k][s];
            ++n;
            details[7]='\0';
            sprintf(fdetails, "%c%c %c%c%c%c%c", details[0], details[1], details[3], details[4], details[5], details[6], details[7]);
        }

        if(OptionCode[k][0]=='T')
        {  
            TakeOffHours=((OptionCode[k][10]-'0')*10)+(OptionCode[k][11]-'0');
            TakeOffMins=((OptionCode[k][13]-'0')*10)+(OptionCode[k][14]-'0');
            passengers=((OptionCode[k][16]-'0')*100)+((OptionCode[k][17]-'0')*10)+(OptionCode[k][18]-'0');
            AddToRunway0T(&r0ThPtr, &r0TtPtr, fdetails, TakeOffHours, TakeOffMins, passengers);

            printQueue(r0ThPtr);
            inTheSystem(r0ThPtr,fdetails);
        }
        fclose(fPointer);
    }
}

void AddToRunway0T(RunZeroTakeOffPtr *r0ThPtr, RunZeroTakeOffPtr *r0TtPtr, char fdetails[], int TakeOffHours, int TakeOffMins, int passengers)
{
    RunZeroTakeOffPtr newPtr;
    int WaitingTime=0;

    newPtr=malloc( sizeof(RunZeroTakeOff) );

    if( newPtr!=NULL)
    {
        strncpy(newPtr->fdetails,fdetails,sizeof(RunZeroTakeOff));
        newPtr->TakeOffHours=TakeOffHours;
        newPtr->TakeOffMins=TakeOffMins;
        newPtr->passengers=passengers;
        newPtr->nextPtr=NULL;
        newPtr->WaitingTime=0;

        printf("%s %d %d %d %d\n", fdetails, TakeOffHours, TakeOffMins, passengers, WaitingTime);

        if( isEmpty(*r0ThPtr))
        {
            *r0ThPtr=newPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            (*r0TtPtr)->nextPtr=newPtr;
        }

        *r0TtPtr=newPtr;
    }
}

int isEmpty(RunZeroTakeOffPtr r0ThPtr)
{
    return r0ThPtr==NULL;
}

int inTheSystem(RunZeroTakeOffPtr currentPtr, char fdetails[])
{
    while(currentPtr->nextPtr!=NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(fdetails,currentPtr->fdetails)==0)
        {
            printf("It's a match!\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Nein\n");
        }
    }
    currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
}
```

My inTheSystem function returns an infinite loop of "Nein". I already know that it wouldn't compare with all the elements in the queue and I really don't know how to do that either. I hope my question was clear enough. I just want to compare the fdetails recently read by the program and compare it to all the previous fdetails read and saved in the queue before.

**Note:** Don't mind the extra declared variables, this program is only half way finished.

Comment: Learn how to use debuggers. They are placid (well, at least most of the time), are helpful, and will fix your problem or at least narrow it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You control your loop by comparing `currentPtr` with `NULL` and
**inside** your loop you have to iterate to the next elment `currentPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;` (you did it outside)

```
int inTheSystem(RunZeroTakeOffPtr currentPtr,char *fdetails[])
{
    int count = 0;
    while ( currentPtr != NULL )
    {
        if(strcmp(fdetails,currentPtr->fdetails)==0)
        {
            count ++;
            printf("It's a match!\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Nein\n");
        }
        currentPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }
    return count;
}
```